# Happy New Year!

Tags: discussion

Not a question, just a small update. Wishing all of my fellow Mage Stackers a great 2015. Thanks for all your contributions last year to the Magento community.

Lets make this an even better year and looking forwards to meeting some of you at Magento conferences this year.

Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome Sander.Wish you Happy new year